# Accessing indexs and length of a heapq?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I originally tried writing an algorithm to solve a 15-puzzle using a priority queue, but my instructor told us that we were required to write in an a* implementation, and recommended that we use a heapq instead of a priority queue. I'm having trouble finding the length/size of my heapq, and accessing elements of my heapq.  I was under the impression that by using a heapq you would be able to access elements in the heapq that you would not be able to access in a priority queue.  However, there don't seem to be any methods for finding the length/retrieving elements from a heapq.  Do any of you know of a way to get the length/element of a heapq or a better suited data structure for this situation?

Answer (score 13):

`heapq` heaps are nothing more than lists whose elements respect a special (non-unique) order.

You can use `len(heap)` on it just like you would on any other list.

```
In [1]: import heapq
In [2]: heap = [40, 10, 20, 30]
In [3]: heapq.heapify(heap)
In [4]: heap
Out[4]: [10, 30, 20, 40]

In [5]: heapq.heappop(heap)
Out[5]: 10

In [6]: heap
Out[6]: [20, 30, 40]

In [7]: len(heap)
Out[7]: 3
```

You should also read [the python documentation for heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html): the [example section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) should interest you.